# AngularJS: How to pass in multiple INT values as string from ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, int, concatenation, angularjs-ng-click

Say for example I have an element like this:

```
<input type="button" id="model{{id}}{{Value}}" ng-click="myFunction(     )">
```

if `id` was 178 and `Value` was 123, how can I make the `ng-click` above concatenate those value and pass them into the function?

Simply by going `ng-click=myFunction(id + Value)` would return a sum, when I would want the value passed into that function to be 178123.

This possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, use the [**`Number.prototype.toString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method:

```
<input type="button" id="model{{id}}{{Value}}" ng-click="myFunction(id.toString() + Value.toString())">
```

Simple **demo**:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);

  function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.id = 178;
    $scope.Value = 123;
    
    $scope.myFunction = function(value) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="button" id="model{{id}}{{Value}}" ng-click="myFunction(id.toString() + Value.toString())" value="Click">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried initially to do `toString` methog as well but I must've done it incorrectly. This did it.

Comment: yea sorry, was waiting for the timer to allow me to do so :)